# Как передать в Lua как глобальную переменную класс через this в LuaBridge

Tags: c++, lua

Сначало я объявил в Lua мой класс и функцию из класса которая мне нужна, а как передать экземпляр класса в котором все это происходит я не знаю...
Вот код -

```
bool Lua_sup::init()
{

    try
    {








        getGlobalNamespace(L)
            .beginClass<Lua_sup>("Lua_sup")// название класса


            .addFunction("register_callback", &Lua_sup::register_callback)

            .endClass();//Мой класс и как передать этот же экземпляр в котором я сейчас нахожусь я не знаю ...



    if (luaL_loadfile(L, m_name.c_str()) || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))   {

        cout << "Error";

        return 0;
    }


    init_state = true;

    return 1;
    }
    catch (exception &e) {
        cout << e.what();
        return 0;
    }

    catch (...) {
        cout << "Unknown error";
        return 0;
    }


}
```

Comment: Код в студию ...

Comment: исправил, код добавил

Comment: Создайте глобальную lua-переменную типа `Lua_sup` и присвойте ей значение `this`, если вам действительна нужна ссылка на этот же объект. Или просто в lua скрипте создайте новый объект `sup = Lua_sup()`.

Comment: А как создать глобальную переменную ?

Comment: Скорее всего вот так: `.addProperty ("var1", this, flase)`. В доках же написано: http://vinniefalco.github.io/LuaBridge/Manual.html#s2.2

Comment: Или даже лучше так: http://vinniefalco.github.io/LuaBridge/Manual.html#s3.1